# Bypassing Windows Credentials using Windows Service

Tags: windows

I have a Windows service and need to supply credentials to the windows logon screen through this service when the computer is in locked state. Is it possible to provide credentials to this screen through windows service?
I read somewhere about the GINA provided by windows but do not want to use it as it accounts for overhead as well as is deprecated in Vista. Is there any other alternative to it?

Comment: This is not possible, or at least it is very difficult - can you detail what you're actually trying to do? There's probably a better way to go about what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: Hi Paul,

I have a windows service which opens up a port for connection. Now let say computer is in locked state. What I want is whenever someone connects to that port and pass windows credentials through command line to that service it actually passes this credentials to the winlogon dialog box, authenticate and unlocks the computer.
Is it possible without the use of GINA?

Comment: Any solution guys?
I read about windows notification packages but could not find any method which can interact with the ms gina and auto logon
Logmein uses this kind of approach in xp and 2k3 but how?

Answer (score 2):

You can't "bypass" log on, but you can implement a [Credential Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx).